# iOS Push Notification PHP error

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, push

Hello I try to send Push Notifications via PHP over the FTP-Hoster square7.ch, but I always get a few errors. The certificate is on the server.
Can anyone help me?

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$streamContext= stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext , 'ssl','local_cert' , 'TestPushApp.pem');
//stream_context_set_option($streamContext , 'ssl' , 'passphrase','password');
$socketClient = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',$error,$errorString,60,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,$streamContext);
$payload['aps']= array('alert' => 'Erste Push Nachricht ueber PHP','sound' => 'default','badge' => '20');
$payload= json_encode($payload);
echo $payload;
$deviceToken = str_replace(' ','','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$message= pack('CnH*',0,32,$devicetoken);
$message= $message . pack ('n',strlen($payload));
$message= $messgae .  $payload;
fwrite($socketClient,$message);
fclose($socketClient);

?>
```

Here's the error message:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /users/michaellll/www/push.php on line 5

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /users/michaellll/www/push.php on line 5

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /users/michaellll/www/push.php on line 5
{"aps":{"alert":"Erste Push Nachricht ueber PHP","sound":"default","badge":"20"}} 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /users/michaellll/www/push.php on line 13

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /users/michaellll/www/push.php on line 14
```

Comment: Please contact your hosting provider, please verify that 2195 or 2196 port is open or not.

Comment: How can I check whether the port is open or not?

Comment: Please contact to your hosting provider

Answer (score 3):

```
  // Push Notification code for IPHONE in PHP 
  $deviceToken = $users_rows['gcm_regid'];
    $passphrase = 'pass1234';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'DrinksterDevelopment.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 120, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    $body['aps'] = array(
       // 'alert' => $_GET["message"].'#'.$_GET["type"].'#'.$_GET["deal_id"],
       'alert' => $_GET["message"],
        'sound' => 'default'
        );
    $body['other'] = $_GET["type"].'#'.$_GET["deal_id"];

    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result_iphone = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result_iphone)
        $msg_iphone = 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    else
        $msg_iphone = 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

     mail('jackbrown00001@gmail.com', 'IOSPushMsgStatus', $msg_iphone);
     fclose($fp);
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code and I get the same error. It seems like that the code is not the problem

Comment: I tried it now on two other servers and it fails every time also with your code it says: (Failed to connect:) Does it work on your server

Answer (score 0):

I think its SSL issue, enable SSL then it might work. One more thing is there `stream_context_set_option($streamContext , 'ssl','local_cert', 'TestPushApp.pem');`
it must be like this

```
$options = array('ssl' => array('local_cert' => 'include/TestPushApp.pem','passphrase' => '//Provided passpharase to you'));
stream_context_set_option($streamContext , $options);
```

and if you are having production certificate i. e pem file then its good to use `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Here file writes function will contain two params only `fwrite($fp, $msg);` not the length of that packaged message.